# Putting Alt Text on Magento Category Thumbnail Images

Tags: magento

Magento has a simple 'upload file' interface for adding the thumbnail images to category pages which does not allow you to assign alt text while uploading.  There is nowhere on the category page to add html for the thumbnail image.

Does anyone know how you assign an alt text to thumbnail images on the main (but not root) category pages?

Thank you.

Comment: Find the template file that controls the display of your subcategories and add an alt to the img src there. Easiest to just use the category name rather than trying to create fields in the admin.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try this - much appreciated!